# Popup Hide Rows

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

```
Private Sub CancelUtility_Click()
UtilityFilter.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub SelectElectricity_Click()
If SelectElectricity = False Then

End Sub

Private Sub SelectGas_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub SelectSolarElectricity_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub SelectSolarThermal_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub SelectSolidWaste_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub SelectWater_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub UtilityFilterText_Click()

End Sub
```

[image]

What I am trying to do is set up a popup box in-order to work as a filter. If a checkbox is not selected I want it to hide each row based on each utility value.

E = Electricity

G = Gas

SE = Solar Electric

ST = Solar Thermal

SW = Solid Waste

W = Water

Currently I have a popup that is opened when the following macro is initiated.

```
Sub UtilityPopup()
UtilityFilter.Show
End Sub
```

The Popup is a custom userform I created called "UtilityFilter"

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the specific question that you are asking? And what have you attempted so far?

Comment: Right now created the popup and the button. Next step is having which ever button isnt selected hide the corresponding rows in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make one function that updates the filter, and call it from all the event functions that you already have. Something like:

```
Private Filters() As String
Private NFilters As Integer

Private Sub UtilityFilterText_Click()
  UpdateFilters
End Sub

Private Sub SelectWater_Click()
  UpdateFilters
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateFilters()
  NFilters = -1
  If CheckboxSelectWater.Value Then AddFilter Filters, "W"
  If CheckboxElectricity.Value Then AddFilter Filters, "E"
  Range("A1:F10").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Filters, Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub

Private Sub AddFilter(Filters() As String, NewValue As String)
  NFilters = NFilters + 1
  ReDim Preserve Filters(NFilters)
  Filters(NFilters) = NewValue
End Sub
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.autofilter%28v=office.14%29.aspx) you can find the documentation of the `Range.AutoFilter` method.